# Issue chaining a task into a group using celery

Tags: python, celery

Here's what I am trying to do I have a bunch of subtasks all chained together and ultimately chained into a group.  I am passing a file name to each task that is being modified along the way and need to get that end file into each of the tasks in the at the end of the chain.  I am currently getting "EncodeError: keys must be a string"  which I presume is from having a group inside of a chaing. My code looks like this:

```
tmp = list()
for f in files:
    tmp.append(task4.s().set(queue='task4'))

chain(task1.s(file_).set(queue='task1'), task2.s().set(queue='task2'),
      task3.s().set(queue='task3'), group(tmp)).delay()
```

I would expect a bunch of task4s to end up receiving and working on the return from task 3

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post the code for your task(s) also?

Comment: So it has something to do with my args.  I switched to pickle of my serializer and it works.

Comment: Can you post how you fixed it as an answer and accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing:

```
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
```

To:

```
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'pickle'
```

Worked for me.